# Help on TileMapRenderer

Tags: libgdx

In my project, I'm trying to render a map using TileMapRenderer. But it doesn't show anything when I render it. But when I use some other files from a tutorial they are rendered correctly.

When debugging my TileAtlas instance shows the size as 0.

I have used Texture Packer UI for packing the images. Comparing with the tutorial's files, I can see that the index starts from 1 in my file and 0 in the tutorial. But changing it to 0 wouldn't work also.

```
map.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
Map
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
Map
  rotate: false
  xy: 32, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 2
Map
  rotate: false
  xy: 64, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 3
Map
  rotate: false
  xy: 96, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 4
Map
  rotate: false
  xy: 128, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 5
```

Here is the begining of the tmx file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="20" height="20" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="a" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
  <image source="map.png" width="256" height="32"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="20" height="20">
  <data>
   <tile gid="2"/>
   <tile gid="2"/>
```

Apart from that the tutorial files and my files seems to be similar.

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: As the problem wasn't solved, I used another texture packer mentioned in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737426/libgdx-application-crashes-when-call-tiledmaprenderer-render) and was able to get it to work. Could be most probably a bug in the texture packer

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the **TiledMapPacker *(com.badlogic.gdx.tiledmappacker.TiledMapPacker from gdx-tiled-preprocessor.jar)***, and **NOT the Texture Packer GUI**.

Usage:

```
libgdx/dist$ java -classpath ./gdx.jar:
        ./extensions/gdx-tools/gdx-tools.jar:
        ./extensions/gdx-tiled-preprocessor/gdx-tiled-preprocessor.jar 
    com.badlogic.gdx.tiledmappacker.TiledMapPacker 
    ~/artifacts/input/ 
    ~/artifacts/output/ 
    --strip-unused
```

TiledMapPacker builds a **packfile** where as Texture Packer GUI builds a **.pack** file.

checkout this article that explains about [packing](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Tiles#Packing) (http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Tiles#Packing). Make sure you have cross checked all the points he mentions, under the above section.